# babel core 7.4.4, using all polyfills by default

Tags: reactjs, babeljs, babel-polyfill

I was tasked to make one of the mobile apps written in react compatible with opera mini in extreme mode. During the testing, I learned that nothing that is in react code works there, however by including this [babel-polyfill](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-polyfill/7.10.4/polyfill.min.js) before `main.js` file it actually is working.

I tried to include it to a Webpack so the code is actually converted instead of including a huge library but without success.

`package.json` file

```
"devDependencies": {
  "@babel/core": "^7.4.4",
  "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.10.1",
  "autoprefixer": "^8.6.3",
  "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
  "copy-webpack-plugin": "latest",
  "css-loader": "latest",
  "file-loader": "latest",
  "html-webpack-plugin": "latest",
  "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.8.0",
  "node-sass": "latest",
  "postcss-loader": "latest",
  "sass-loader": "latest",
  "style-loader": "latest",
  "url-loader": "latest",
  "webpack": "latest",
  "webpack-cli": "latest",
  "webpack-dev-server": "latest"
},
"dependencies": {
  "react": "^16.13.1",
  "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
  "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0"
}
```

`.babelrc` file:

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/env", "@babel/react"],
  "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"]
}
```

`webpack.config.js` file:

```
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");

const htmlPlugin = new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
  template: "./src/index.html",
  filename: "index.html",
});

module.exports = {
  output: {
    publicPath: "/",
    filename: "js/main.[hash:8].js",
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: "babel-loader",
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|ico|svg|eot|ttf|woff|woff2)$/,
        loader: "url-loader",
        options: {
          limit: 25000,
          outputPath: "assets/",
          name: "[name].[hash:8].[ext]",
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.(scss|sass|css)$/i,
        use: [
          {
            loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          },
          "css-loader",
          "postcss-loader",
          "sass-loader",
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".js", ".jsx", ".json"],
  },
  plugins: [
    htmlPlugin,
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: "css/style.[hash:8].css",
    }),
  ],
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: {
      rewrites: [{ from: /^\/$/, to: "/index.html" }],
    },
  },
};
```

How these can be modified so I don't have to include entire `babel-polyfill.min.js` and Webpack + babel will actually convert the code to work?

**--EDIT**

I had success with following changes:

`package.json` file

```
...
"browserslist": [
  "dead"
],
...
```

`.babelrc` file:

```
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        "useBuiltIns": "entry",
        "corejs": 3
      }
    ],
    "@babel/preset-react"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
    [
      "@babel/transform-runtime",
      {
        "corejs": 3
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

`webpack.config.js` file:

```
...
entry: "./src/index.js",
...
```

Once this setup is in place, i have to manually include `import "core-js";` at the top of every file that is part of project so for example:

- index.js
- App.js
- components/events.jsx
- components/popup.jsx
- and so on...

is there a way to avoid that inclusion by some configuration in `webpack` or `babel` ? (i tried `"useBuiltIns": "usage"` instead of `entry` but it doesnt include all needed polyfills)

Answer (score 0):

I was gonna suggest you drop babel-polyfill since it's [deprecated as of 7.4.0](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-polyfill) but then saw your edit.

If you want to avoid importing core-js everywhere you should use `"useBuiltIns": "usage"`.

I think the reason it doesn't polyfill everything is because your browserslist query doesn't match to opera mini according to (https://browserl.ist/?q=dead), you should specify it, something like:

```js
...
"browserslist": [
  "dead",
  "op_mini all"
],
...
```

Comment: sadly no, i already try to include many things into the `browserslist`, surely all related to old and limited browsers and it still doesnt work, in the debug log you can see that it barely includes any polyfills as opposite to when you specify `entry` instead

Comment: I can add that browser i am working with is `Opera mini 4.5` released in `2007` that runs on devices like `Sony Ericsson k800i`